# winzip cli how to suppress evaluation warning?

Tags: winzip

In my product we are using winzipCLI to zip packages. After a long time i seeing an issue not able to resolve it. A evaluation acceptance message is thrown in CLI which is causing my build system to fail. I found the issue by manually running the winzip cli and below the evalution question asked ....How to suppress it? Any options? or any script? or...etc?

C:\Program Files\WinZip>WZZIP.EXE -a test.zip *.txt
WinZip(R) Command Line Support Add-On Version 4.0 32-bit (Build 10480)
Copyright (c) 1991-2013 WinZip International LLC - All Rights Reserved

THANK YOU FOR TRYING WINZIP COMMAND LINE ADD-ON
This is a fully functional version for EVALUATION USE ONLY
This notice is not displayed with registered Standard and Pro editions of
WinZip.
Please go to www.winzip.com to order WinZip.
(press any key to continue (Ctrl-C to quit))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, buy a license for WinZip.

(Stack Overflow is not the place to ask questions like "How can I avoid paying for this piece of commercial software?"  If in fact you *have* bought a license and you're still getting that message then I apologise for misjudging you and you should take it up with WinZip tech support.)